# Xamarin.Forms (VS): Properties from XAML shown as missing. Builds successful

Tags: visual-studio

Just about a few hours ago I got here:

[image]

`InitializeComponent();` and `label_link` both are properties that either come from XAML behind or init this.

Intellisense shows them as non existing.
Builds however are successful. This issue just appeared out of the blue.

I tried:

Restarting VS
Restarting MAC
cleared BIN and OBJ folder
Cleaned and rebuilded
Unloaded and reloaded everything
deleted .VS (hidden folder)

Other solutions are working fine, it is only this specific problem.

However, this exists in every class of my project now.

Since this is VS for MAC there is no way to reinstall this.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

So after trying out everything over and over again,

i retraced my steps to what I did prior which was installing
mobile.buildtools and try and set up the sercrets.json file. I removed both cleaned and resetted everything again and finally intellisense was working again and there are no more red lines underneath my code.